# jQuery File Upload using Requirejs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, require, jquery-file-upload

I have been trying [this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) work it out in intranet environment, so obviously there are no CDNs.
Later from [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-use-jQuery-File-Upload-with-RequireJS/ad943a205420db804ead7f9515224dd0c5a8b241) article I found we need to load the 'load-image', 'tmpl' and 'canvas-to-blob' as AMD using RequireJs.

I have a `main.js` as follows:

```
(function () {
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '/Scripts',
        waitSeconds: 800,
        paths: {
            'jquery': ['/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery', 'jquery-1.10.2'],
            'jquery.ui.widget': ['/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget'],
            'jquery.fileupload': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload',
            'jquery.fileupload-ui': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui',
            'jquery.fileupload-image': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-image',
            'jquery.fileupload-validate': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate',
            'jquery.fileupload-video': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-video',
            'jquery.fileupload-audio': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio',
            'jquery.fileupload-process': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-process',
            'jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui',
            'jquery.iframe-transport': ['jquery-1.10.2', '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/jquery.iframe-transport'],
            'load-image': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image',
            'load-image-meta': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-meta',
            'load-image-exif': ['/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-meta', '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-exif'],
            'load-image-ios': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-ios',
            'canvas-to-blob': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/canvas-to-blob',
            'tmpl': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/tmpl',
            'bootstrap': 'Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
            'app': 'app'
        }
    });

    require(['jquery', 'app'], function ($,app) {
        $(function () {
            app.init();
        });
    });

})();
```

and `app.js`:

```
define(
        ['jquery', 'tmpl', 'load-image', 'canvas-to-blob', 'jquery.iframe-transport', 'jquery.fileupload-ui'], function () {
            return {
                init: function ($) {
                    alert();
                    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                        url: '/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx',
                        add: function (e, data) {
                            console.log("add", data);
                        },
                        submit: function (e, data) {
                            console.log("submit", data);
                        },
                        change: function (e, data) {
                            console.log("change", data);
                        },
                        send: function (e, data) {
                            console.log("send", data);
                            data.url = url + "'" + data.files[0].name + "'";
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

There are no errors in console and nothing is logging in the console. The `app.init()` is not invoked and when files are selected nothing happens? Not sure what I am missing or what is wrong in my code. I have searched many forums and couldn't get through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my site i change the line

```
'load-image-exif': ['/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-meta', '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-exif'],
```

by

```
'load-image-exif': '/Content/jQueryFileUpload/js/load-image-exif',
```

and is working fine.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" or "this answer worked" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: @chiwangc  Avoid the thanks in the answer, you must read that there is an answer with the example. I think this is ok.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-add) the request is send when `submit()` is called to the `data object`.

The default `add()` callback is the one's which execute the submit action. Your error is you override it without calling submit function. So just add it like :

```
add: function (e, data) {
    console.log("add", data);
    data.submit();
},
```

But you can call it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I cannot see anything logging in console, which means the add is not invoking.